# align AlertDialog buttons to center

Tags: android, button, alignment, android-alertdialog

I use this codes for Android (Java) programming:

```
public static MessageBoxResult showOk(
        Context context, String title, String message, String okMessage)
{
    okDialogResult = MessageBoxResult.Closed;

    // make a handler that throws a runtime exception when a message is received
    final Handler handler = new Handler()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message mesg)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    };

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alert.setTitle(title);
    alert.setMessage(message);

    alert.setPositiveButton(okMessage, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            okDialogResult = MessageBoxResult.Positive;
            handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = alert.show();


    // align button to center
    Button b = (Button) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
    b.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    // loop till a runtime exception is triggered.
    try { Looper.loop(); }
    catch(RuntimeException e2) {}

    return okDialogResult;
}
```

My problem is how make center the button? As you see I try to align button to cnenter using `Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL` (also `.CENTER`) but nothing changes. The button is almost in right position.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This worked for me :

```
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });


    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show(); //show() should be called before dialog.getButton().


    final Button positiveButton = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams positiveButtonLL = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) positiveButton.getLayoutParams();
    positiveButtonLL.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    positiveButton.setLayoutParams(positiveButtonLL);
```

Comment: What is reference `positiveBtn`?

Comment: Does not work on Android 7.1.1 but @Scott Brown's solution below works just fine.

Answer (score 41):

Use crtn's method, but instead of changing the `LayoutParam's` gravity, change its width to `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;`

Comment: Works fine. To be superclear to lazy people like me: Replace the line <positiveButtonLL.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;> with <positiveButtonLL.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;>

Comment: @JohanLund how I can set if we have 3 buttons like left, center, right?

Answer (score 16):

If you want to have Positive And Negative Buttons at the same time (Large & Center), you can use something like this:

[image: Dialog Positive & Negative Buttons]

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("Title");
alertDialog.setMessage("Message");

alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "No",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                 dialog.dismiss();
            }
         });
alertDialog.show();

Button btnPositive = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
Button btnNegative = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnPositive.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.weight = 10;
btnPositive.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
btnNegative.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is something really work.

The parent of the 3 buttons (neutral, positive ve and negative) is ButtonBarLayout, which extends LinearLayout. To centralize a view in LinearLayout, weight, width and  layout_gravity(but not gravity) is important, and these code works perfectly:

```js
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); //create a new one
layoutParams.weight = 1.0 f;
layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER; //this is layout_gravity
alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: It's works. also @frank's solution also works. but I prefer this one.

Comment: Just to clarify, make sure to pass the button you desire to display in #getButton(AlertDialog.[BUTTON_YOU_WANT]), and make sure to set the layoutParams after you call alertDialog.show()

Answer (score 9):

Tried crtn's method and Scott Brown's modification, both didn't render how I liked.

crtn's solution didn't change the appearance of the buttons for me at all (I'm using `android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog`) and Scott Brown's solution made my positive button extend past the edge of the dialog parent.

For `Theme_Material_Light_Dialog` the buttons are contained within a `LinearLayout` subclass that uses a blank View as its 2nd (index 1) element to push the buttons right.

I grab the `Button` ref like crtn does:

```
AlertDialog dialog = bld.create();
dialog.show(); //show() MUST be called before dialog.getButton
Button positiveButton = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
```

But then I set the leftSpacer to View.GONE and the parent's gravity to CENTER_HORIZONTAL

```
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) positiveButton.getParent();
parent.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
View leftSpacer = parent.getChildAt(1);
leftSpacer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

This has the advantage that it doesn't break the dialog's button stacking behavior. The disadvantage is that if the internal layout changes, it will break, so YMMV.

Comment: It works, the best solution I've found thanks a lot!

Comment: I had the same problem than op and change the button gravity to center didn't work for me. Your solution works great, thanks.

Comment: This solution Works best, accepted solution didnt help me and scottbrowns solution wont work for me as its just match parent as i wanted to align it left and not center.

Answer (score 3):

Ended up with this extension for Kotlin:

```
fun AlertDialog.withCenteredButtons() {
    val positive = getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
    val negative = getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE)

    //Disable the material spacer view in case there is one
    val parent = positive.parent as? LinearLayout
    parent?.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
    val leftSpacer = parent?.getChildAt(1)
    leftSpacer?.visibility = View.GONE

    //Force the default buttons to center
    val layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )

    layoutParams.weight = 1f
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER

    positive.layoutParams = layoutParams
    negative.layoutParams = layoutParams
}
```

And use with:

```
.show().withCenteredButtons()
```

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are using the AlertDialog from the Support library.

If that's the case try replacing your import to android.app.AlertDialog.

Answer (score 1):

Use`android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` which will align your positive and negative buttons in center.

`android.app.AlertDialog` will place the button in the top leaving 16dp space in bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the positive, negative and neutral buttons, hide both the positive and neutral buttons, and put the negative button where the neutral button is supposed to be(center) by using LayoutParams.

in onCreateView:

```
dialog = builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        })
                 .setPositiveButton(R.string.go_on, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                     }
                 })
                 .setNeutralButton(R.string.do_nothing, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                     }
                 })
                 .create();
```

in onStart():

```
 super.onStart();

    final Button positiveButton = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
   positiveButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   final Button neutralButton = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
   neutralButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   final Button negativeButton = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
   negativeButton.setLayoutParams(neutralButton.getLayoutParams());
```

Answer (score -3):

```
       IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
        Icons.logout,
        color: Colors.black,
        size: 40,
      ),
            onTap: () {
              return showDialog<String>(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  title: Text(
                    'Are you sure you want to logout',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                        child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        ///yes
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () =>
                              Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context,
                                  SecondScreen.id, (route) => false),
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            width: 70,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                color: mainColor),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                'Yes',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),

                        ///no
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            width: 70,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                color: Colors.white,
                                border: Border.all(color: mainColor)),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                'No',
                                style: TextStyle(color: mainColor),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ))
                  ],
                ),
              );
          
            },
          ),
```

Comment: You should add more details to your answers instead of just posting a code snippet.