# Order of buttons in an AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I build an `AlertBox` with 3 buttons (positiv, neutral & negativ):

```
myDialogBox = AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.MyAlertDialogTheme);
```

Then I set the buttons like so:

```
myDialogBox.setPositiveButton(sBuyAtlas, new alogInterface.OnClickListener() 
myDialogBox.setNeutralButton(sBuyAtlas, new alogInterface.OnClickListener() 
myDialogBox.setNegativeButton(sBuyAtlas, new alogInterface.OnClickListener()
```

At runtime the order is 
positiv - negativ - neutral

How can I achieve the cancel to be right. It is common, that "cancel" is on the rigth side of an dialog. How can I do that, without missusing the neutral as cancel ?

Comment: You can make custom dialog to achieve that..

Comment: So I really need to customize my own dialog to do that. No other way ? I would like to have my code as small as possible.

Comment: Its better if you  create custom Alert dialog . However you can have look into [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743038/align-alertdialog-buttons-to-center) to change alignment in the default one .

Answer (score 1):

You can get remove all buttons and then add them again in your preferred order

```
 AlertDialog alerDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder().build();
    Button posBtn = (Button) alertDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
    Button negBtn = (Button) alertDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.button2);
    Button neuBtn = (Button) alertDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.button3);

    //get parent ViewGroup
     ViewGroup parentLayout = (ViewGroup) posBtn.getParent();

    //get child indexes
    int posIndex = parentLayout.indexOfChild(posBtn);
    int negindex = parentLayout.indexOfChild(negBtn);
    int neuIndex = parentLayout.indexOfChild(neuBtn);

     parentLayout.removeAllViews();
     parentLayout.addView(neuIndex,posBtn); //< --- swapping neutral and positive
     parentLayout.addView(posIndex,neuBtn);
     parentLayout.addView(negIndex,negBtn);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I guess if I have to create layouts for buttons, then I can also create a custom dialog from scratch.

Comment: Oops sorry , you no need to create layout , It’s the default alert dialog itself

Answer (score 0):

@Ranjan answer should also work meanwhile if you try to set the custom dialog here is the system dailog clone layout, just manipulate buttons and order it according to your requirement and set as the view to alert dialog.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parentPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="9dip"
    android:paddingBottom="3dip"
    android:paddingStart="3dip"
    android:paddingEnd="1dip">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/topPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="54dip"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/title_template"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="9dip"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dip"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dip">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:paddingTop="6dip"
                android:paddingEnd="10dip"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_dialog_info" />
            <com.android.internal.widget.DialogTitle android:id="@+id/alertTitle"
                style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/titleDivider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:src="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dark" />
        <!-- If the client uses a customTitle, it will be added here. -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/contentPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="2dip"
            android:paddingBottom="12dip"
            android:paddingStart="14dip"
            android:paddingEnd="10dip"
            android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/message"
                style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip" />
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/customPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+android:id/custom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/buttonPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="54dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="4dip"
            android:paddingStart="2dip"
            android:paddingEnd="2dip"
            android:measureWithLargestChild="true">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/leftSpacer"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="gone" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/rightSpacer"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

set the view back to alert dialog

```
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog, null);
myDialogBox.setView(dialogView);
```