# How to fix Button Alignment on ProgressDialog

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a phone test device and I am having trouble with the ui of the buttons of it.

This code is fine with other devices but the alignment of the button isn't good in the said device above.

I tried doing all these but none worked.
[align AlertDialog buttons to center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743038/align-alertdialog-buttons-to-center)

I also tried putting additional buttons and setting it to invisible but I only want to use it if I really can't find a better solution.

Here is my code:

```
progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
progressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, activity.getString(ResourceUtils.getResourceId(activity, "lbl_cancel", ResourceType.STRING)), this);
progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(this);
progressDialog.show();
```

[Here is the picture of the Button alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRmiM.png)

Comment: ProgressDialog is now deprecated, you should find other way.

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows

```
progressDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```