# align alertdialog buttons to center with Style

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

This is my custom alert dialog :

```
    <style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/alert_bg</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/NegativeButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">3dip</item>
</style>

<style name="PositiveButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/alert_btn_yes</item>
</style>
<style name="NegativeButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/alert_btn_no</item>

</style>
```

[image]

I want align buttons to center like this :

[image: an]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [align AlertDialog buttons to center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743038/align-alertdialog-buttons-to-center)

Comment: Why not just set a custom view to `AlertDialog` with same Style and Appearance. It will be easy and full proof solution .

Answer (score 0):

You can get positive/negative button at runtime `dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)` and change layout params property and align your buttons to center.

```
val btnPositive: Button = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
val lpPositive = btnPositive.layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams
lpPositive.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
btnPositive.layoutParams = lpPositive
```

Comment: @H.Mohammadi using custom view is better choice and help you in future changes